# MS Access sql query for forum tables

Tags: ms-access

If you will find this question to simple for the forum - blame it on me and I will apologize, because I am no more than just a novice to this issues.

I have this two tables in MS Access:

table Items and  table Comments connected  by Comments.parent ID = Items.ID.

I need a query that will displayed last 10 records from Items table, each record containing

```
Item.id 
Item.title
Item.text
Item,date_modified
count of Comments [if any]  for the Item 
last Comments[if any] guestName
last Comments[if any] date_modified
```

So far I have got something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10  t4.id, t4.* FROM
(
SELECT Items.id AS item_id , Items.*,  t3.guestName , t3.modified AS comment_date  
,(SELECT count(*) FROM Comments where parentid = Items.id) as comentscount 
FROM Items 
,( SELECT  t2.id as commentID, t2.guestName , t2.modified, t2.parentid  FROM Comments as t2 ORDER BY t2.modified DESC  ) as t3 
WHERE 
(Items.id = t2.parentid  AND  t3.commentID = (SELECT max(id) FROM Comments where parentid = Items.id)) 
ORDER BY Items.modified DESC 

UNION

SELECT Items.id AS item_id, Items.* ,  null AS guestName,  null AS comment_date, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM Comments where parentid = Items.id) as comentscount 
FROM Items
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM Comments where parentid = Items.id)  = 0 
) AS t4
```

Well. It is working but I keep asking myself if this could be done in a more simple way.

Any suggestions will be more then welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Flinsch and Remou,thank you very much for your reactions. I had to do some minor adjustments but the general ideas you send were both very usefull to me. Both examples gave me the push into the right direction to improve my sql knowledge and I have got the query working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10
Item.id,
Item.title,
Item.text,
Item.modified,
COUNT(Comment.id) AS count_of_comments,
(SELECT TOP 1 Comment.guest_name FROM Comment WHERE Comment.parentid = Item.id ORDER BY Comment.modified DESC) AS last_guest_name,
MAX(Comment.modified) AS last_comment_date
FROM Item
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Comment.parentid = Item.id
GROUP BY Item.id
ORDER BY Item.modified DESC
```

I'm not sure if the inner `SELECT` statement could also be integrated more appropriately. Maybe we could also `ORDER BY Comments.modified DESC` and then just "select" `guest_name` rejecting the nested `SELECT` statement, but I'm not sure.

(I have not tested it.)

Comment: Thank you Flinsch. I have got your example working like this:


SELECT TOP 10

Items.id, Items.title,Items.text,Items.modified, 

COUNT(Comments.id) AS count_of_comments,

(SELECT TOP 1 Comments.guest_name FROM Comments WHERE Comments.parentid = Items.id ORDER BY 
Comment.modified DESC) AS last_guest_name,

(SELECT TOP 1 Comments.modified FROM Comments WHERE Comments.parentid = Items.id ORDER BY Comments.modified DESC) AS last_comment_date

FROM Items

LEFT JOIN Comments ON Comments.parentid = Items.id

GROUP BY Items.id

ORDER BY Items.modified DESC

Answer (score 0):

How about something on the lines of :

```
SELECT TOP 10
       Item.id,
       Item.title,
       Item.text,
       Item.date_modified,
       c.CommentCount,
       c.LastComment,
       c.LastGuestName,
       c.LastModDate
FROM Item
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ParentID, 
       Count(ParentID) As CommentCount, 
       Last(Comment) As LastComment, 
       Last(guestName) As LastGuestName,
       Last(date_modified) As LastModDate
FROM Comments
GROUP BY ParentID
ORDER BY date_modified DESC) c
ON Item.ItemID=c.ParentID
ORDER BY item.date_modified
```

Comment: Thank you Remou. I have got your example working like this:

SELECT TOP 10
 Items.id,
 Items.titel,
 Items.text,
 Items.modified
, c.commentsCOUNT
, c.guest
, c.commentDATE
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT 
parentId,  Count(parentid) AS commentsCOUNT , LAST(guestName)  AS guest, LAST(modified) AS commentDATE, LAST(Text)
FROM Comments
GROUP BY ParentID
ORDER BY LAST(modified) DESC ) c
ON Items.Id=c.ParentId
ORDER BY items.modified DESC